# Is the currentdate in Worflow designer a static one

Tags: designer-workflow, pause

this is my workflow:
[image]

Yesterday I received email from "**if**" condition. Today i received email from "**else**" condition. knowing that my calendar has entries for today! 
so my guess is that today is not updated in SharePoint Designer.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior (`Yesterday I received an email from "if" condition. Today I received an email from "else" condition.`) that you have received is correct!

To make it clear, Let's review your above workflow steps,

- You are checking the start time of the current item that initiates the workflow if it is equal today or not.
- Then pause one hour.
- Then go to back to check again.

All the above steps have been only applied on an item that initiates this workflow instance whether in creating or changing or even manually.

So yesterday `the start time of the current item` was equal today so you have received an email from **if** condition and Today the `start time of the current item` that initiates this workflow becomes is not equal today so you have received from **the else** condition.

So you should be aware of every item in the list has its own workflow instance,  and the workflow instance will be only applied to the item that initiates it, not for all items in the list.

In fact, I don't know what's your scenario to do your workflow like this but I think this is not a good way to build your workflow without `End Workflow` action!! With this way will lead to infinity workflow instance for each item in your list.

Comment: Hi!

The idea is walk a calendar daily and then use the day event info to construct a mail.

Comment: Hi @MohamedAyach is your comment is a provided solution? I can't got it so should you elaborate your comment please!, also please don't hesitate to inform me if you need more calcification ,

Comment: @M.Qassasa 
no it is not a solution it is what I need to achieve! I Have a calendar that has many events and I need to walk through day by day hope you get it.